# How to run the exec-maven-plugin if a system property id set in Maven 3.x?

Tags: maven, properties, maven-3, pom.xml

I want to run the 'exec-maven-plugin' if a system property is set.  How do I accomplish this in Maven 3.x?

For example, given:

```
mvn clean install -DrunTheExec="yes"
```

Then how can I implement this logic:

```
<!-- if $(runTheExec) == yes then run this plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just about to add the same suggestion as Johnathon, but using the profile a little differently.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>runTheExec</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
```

then to activate it:

```
mvn clean install -PrunTheExec
```

Comment: Both are good answers, but I'll have to pick this one as the answer since the default option is a nice add.  I'll vote up both answers.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to define a profile in your pom, with the plugin defined inside of it. In your example, this would be:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>runTheExec</name>
        <value>yes</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```